# Changing name of keys,values and action url of form before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there anyway to change name of keys,values and action url of form before submit. I have a form but simple input looks something like that:

```
<input type="text" name="Af25fsg2" value="BGHfGSG" />
```

Characters are rearranged and I need to set them to normal by javascript or jquery function and them submit the form.

Comment: You can use onSubmit event and can change the required attributes of the elements .. such as $(".form").attr("action","YourAction");
$("#Af25fsg2").attr("name","NewName"); and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="frmKey" name="Af25fsg2" value="BGHfGSG" />
```

**Script**

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){// Let myform is id of your form
    $(this).attr('action','newaction');
    $('#frmKey').val('newkey');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need subscribe [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event handler of the form. You can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to change the value of attribute.

```
$("formSelector").submit(function(){      
    $(this).attr("action", "newurl"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this on any click or an event which you are using

```
jQuery("input").attr("name","changeName");
jQuery("input").val("changeValue");
jQuery("FORMID").attr("action","CHANGEACTION");
```

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

HTML

```
<form action='' name='myform' id="myform" method='POST'>
      <input type="text" name="Af25fsg2" value="BGHfGSG" id="textInput" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
   var input = $('#textInput').val(); // Get the value here, do whatever you want to it
   var name = $(this).attr('name'); // Get the name here, do whatever you want to it. 
   $(this).attr('action', "http://www.mysite.com/" + textInput + ".html"); // Set the action here. 
});
```